# MD5 of NSData in macOS Catalina 10.15 returns different result to macOS 10.14

Tags: objective-c, macos, md5, macos-catalina

Running the MD5 implementation below returns a different result in macOS 10.15 than it does on 10.14

The NSData object should be the same (unsure the best way to check this - allocating to NSString is (null) in both scenarios. I have checked the length and both are the same)

```
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( self.bytes, (int)self.length, result );
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ];
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
The NSData object is created with the below (obfuscated) code:

```
NSData *firstData = [self.firstString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *archivedData = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:secondString requiringSecureCoding:NO error:nil] mutableCopy];

[archivedData appendData:firstData];

return [archivedData MD5];
```

Edit:
It actually looks like it's the NSData object that's different. The same string is passed into the code above, hard coded in a test app.
There is still a difference between 10.14 and 10.15

Hex Output:

```
10.15
62706C69 73743030 D4010203 04050607 0A582476 65727369 6F6E5924 61726368 69766572 5424746F 7058246F 626A6563 74731200 0186A05F 100F4E53 4B657965 64417263 68697665 72D10809 54726F6F 748001A2 0B0C5524 6E756C6C 5F102C34 32373539 3930432D 42423235 36363143 2D434146 42424136 412D3031 46303242 42302D38 45364444 46303508 111A2429 3237494C 5153565C 00000000 00000101 00000000 0000000D 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000008B 47642437 2A752877 2B587852 684A7537 73342D39 39234625 305B413F 437A7434 4A722871 32245672 30406D58 50337251 71374644 372B522A 2D28462F 683E5F4B

10.14
62706C69 73743030 D4010203 04050609 0A582476 65727369 6F6E5824 6F626A65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6F701200 0186A0A2 07085524 6E756C6C 5F102C34 32373539 3930432D 42423235 36363143 2D434146 42424136 412D3031 46303242 42302D38 45364444 4630355F 100F4E53 4B657965 64417263 68697665 72D10B0C 54726F6F 74800108 111A232D 32373A40 6F818489 00000000 00000101 00000000 0000000D 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000008B 47642437 2A752877 2B587852 684A7537 73342D39 39234625 305B413F 437A7434 4A722871 32245672 30406D58 50337251 71374644 372B522A 2D28462F 683E5F4B
```

Comment: They probably changed the implementation between 10.14 and 10.15.  Does the data from 10.14 unarchive correctly on 10.15 (and vice versa)?

Comment: You're right, the `archivedDataWithRootObject` method is returning differently

Comment: Not sure what I can do about that @trojanfoe ?

Comment: So I assume as long as it actually works there is nothing wrong, apart from it's messing-up your hashing.  You need to hash the *base data*, not the archived data, and then you have control over changes etc.

Comment: It's not recomended to use MD5. Use SHA256 instead.